# JAX-WS request xml works when tested with SOAP UI, but doesnt work when called from application

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am working on a JAX-WS client for a post code lookup service. I traced the request xml as follows:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <S:Body>
              <ns2:getRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www-schema/WSAddressLookup/">
                     <ACSH>
                           <USERID>d19107</USERID>
                           <ROLEID>tester</ROLEID>
                     </ACSH>
                     <ACAH>
                           <COMPLETIONCODE>0</COMPLETIONCODE>
                           <SERVICENAME>paris.CALS.1.Get.XXINFO</SERVICENAME>
                     </ACAH>
                     <ACXMLBODY>
                           <AddressLookupRequest>
                                  <RequestRecord>
                                         <OperationType>Get</OperationType>
                                         <AddressListKey>10376051.00</AddressListKey>
                                  </RequestRecord>
                           </AddressLookupRequest>
                     </ACXMLBODY>
              </ns2:getRequest>
       </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I tested this using SOAP UI and it times out.

It expects the ns2 namespace to be declared within the soap envelope as below:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www-schema/WSAddressLookup/" >
       <S:Body>
              <ns2:getRequest>
                     <ACSH>
                           <USERID>d19107</USERID>
                           <ROLEID>tester</ROLEID>
                     </ACSH>
                     <ACAH>
                           <COMPLETIONCODE>0</COMPLETIONCODE>
                           <SERVICENAME>paris.CALS.1.Get.XXINFO</SERVICENAME>
                     </ACAH>
                     <ACXMLBODY>
                           <AddressLookupRequest>
                                  <RequestRecord>
                                         <OperationType>Get</OperationType>
                                         <AddressListKey>10376051.00</AddressListKey>
                                  </RequestRecord>
                           </AddressLookupRequest>
                     </ACXMLBODY>
              </ns2:getRequest>
       </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

So I wrote a handler, as shown below:

```
public class LoggingHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);

       FileOutputStream fop = null;
       File file;
       FileOutputStream fop1 = null;
       File file1;

       public boolean handleMessage (SOAPMessageContext c) {
              LOG.info("Inside handleMessage of LoggingHandler");
              SOAPMessage msg = c.getMessage();

              try {

                     boolean request = ((Boolean) c.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)).booleanValue();

                     file = new File("c:/work/soapRequest.txt");
                     fop = new FileOutputStream(file);


                     // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                     if (!file.exists()) {
                           file.createNewFile();
                     }

                     if (request) { // This is a request message.
                           // Write the message to the output stream 
                           SOAPEnvelope envelope = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope(); //get the SOAP Message envelope
                           envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns2", "http://www-schema/WSAddressLookup/");       
                           msg.saveChanges();
                           c.setMessage(msg);
                           msg.writeTo(fop);                        
                     }
              }
              catch (Exception e) {}
              finally{
                     try {
                           if (fop != null) {
                                  fop.close();
                           }
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                           LOG.info("Logging handler Exception: ", e);
                     }
              }
              return true;
       }

       public boolean handleFault (SOAPMessageContext c) {
              SOAPMessage msg = c.getMessage();
              try {
                     file = new File("c:/work/soapResponse.txt");
                     fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

                     // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                     if (!file.exists()) {
                           file.createNewFile();
                     }
                     msg.writeTo (fop);
                     LOG.info("soap fault written");
              }
              catch (Exception e) {}
              finally{
                     try {
                           if (fop != null) {
                                  fop.close();
                           }
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
              }
              return true;
       }

       public void close (MessageContext c) {
       }

       public Set getHeaders() {
              // Not required for logging
              return null;
       }
}
```

I add a namespace declaration to the envelope and write the request xml to a local file. The request xml is now exactly same as the expected request shown above. I tested this using SOAP UI and it returns the correct response xml. However it times out when I call the service from the application. The fault handler method writes the fault message to a local file and it shows a timeout message.

Is there any chance, that the request traced is not the one being used to call the service?(despite the lines `msg.saveChanges();` and `c.setMessage(msg);`

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: According to XML Schema specification, you can give the `ns1` namespace on the `<Envelope>` element or the `<getRequest>` element, makes no difference to any compliant XML parser.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I have no idea why it times out in the first case. However it works only when ns2 is declared in the soap envelope(even in SOAP UI).